# CreateTimerQueue() Where do the thread come from?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am about to use CreateTimerQueue() but would like some clarification on some points.

Documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx

Example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms687003(v=vs.85).aspx

The link above suggests that the callback function supplied to CreateTimerQueue() is run in a separate thread, but where does this thread come from? Is it created and destroyed each time the callback function is called? Or is there a thread pool somewhere managed by the O/S? I've never used a thread pool before myself but I thought I would have to implement one myself and send tasks to each thread as needed, which is obviously incorrect.

A link to good article would be nice as would a comparison as to linux equivalents.

Thanks

Comment: Windows maintains a default thread pool for these callbacks.  Same one that's used by the QueueUserWorkItem() function.  It is managed by Windows itself, no need to help.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation you linked to, the callback occurs in a worker thread by default:

> WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT
>   0x00000000
>   By default, the callback function is queued to a non-I/O worker thread.

For more information about worker threads, see the MSDN page, [Thread Pools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yep I read that but it does not say that this thread belong to o/s managed worker pool, I suspected as per my question it but wanted conformation. How does this compare to what is available under a linux platform?

Comment: The documentation for CreateTimerQueueTimer could certainly be clearer about that.  However, the thread pool is mentioned in the remarks, and CreateTimerQueueTimer is on the list of [thread pool API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions, so it is safe to conclude that it does indeed use the thread pool.  (Also, the phrase "non-I/O worker thread" is only meaningful in the context of the thread pool.)  I don't know whether Linux has any equivalent to the thread pool or not.